# Updating EnvironmentObject pushed me back

Tags: swiftui

I have two views ListView and DetailView

ListView:

```
@EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData

var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(userData.packs) { pack in
                if pack.added {
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(packIndex: self.userData.packs.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == pack.id })!)) {
                        MyRowViewDoesntMatter(pack: pack)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
    }
```

DetailView:

```
@EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData
var packIndex: Int

VStack {
       List {
           VStack {
               .... some Vies ... doesn't matter
       .navigationBarItems(trailing:



      THE PROBLEM IS HERE (BELOW)

      Button(action: {
               self.userData.packs[self.packIndex].added.toggle()
      }) {
        Image(systemName: self.userData.packs[self.packIndex].added ? "plus.circle.fill" : "plus.circle")
      }
      ...
```

The problem is when I click on button in the navigationBarItems in DetailView. The "added" property of the "@EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData" is updated and the user's screen is going back (to the RowView). I fond out that the problem with EnvironmentObject, because the data is updated and View tries to rerender (?) that is why it pushes me back?

How to fix it? I want to stay at the DetailView screen after clicking the button.

P.S. I need to use EnvironmentObject type because then when I go back I need to see the results.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Would you show the `pack` type?

Comment: `struct Pack: Identifiable {
    var id: String
    added: Bool
}`

Answer (score 1):

Here is possible approach (by introducing some kind of selection). As `NavigationView` does not allow to remove link from stack (as identifier of stacked navigation), probably also worth considering separate view model for `DetailView` to be applied into common container on finish editing.

Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4.

Some replication of your code, used for testing:

```
struct ListView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var userData: PushBackUserData

    @State private var selectedPack: Pack? = nil
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                ForEach(Array(userData.packs.enumerated()), id: \.element.id) { i, pack in
                    NavigationLink("Pack \(pack.id)", destination:
                        DetailView(pack: self.$selectedPack)
                            .onAppear {
                                self.selectedPack = pack
                            }
                            .onDisappear {
                                self.userData.packs[i].added = self.selectedPack?.added ?? false
                            }
                    ).isHidden(!pack.added)
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @Binding var pack: Pack?
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
               List {
                   VStack {
                    Text("Pack \(pack?.id ?? "<none>")")
                   }
                }
               .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                  Button(action: {
                       self.pack?.added.toggle()
                  }) {
                    Image(systemName: pack?.added ?? false ? "plus.circle.fill" : "plus.circle")
                  }
                )
            }
    }
}
```

just convenient helper extension

```
extension View {
    func isHidden(_ hidden: Bool) -> some View {
        Group {
            if hidden { self.hidden() }
            else { self }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have already tried that. Unfortunately it doesn't help. Because I need to update the `@EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData` in `DetailView` that will cause changing here `self.userData.packs.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == pack.id })!` in `ListView` and as a result it pushes me back from `DetailView` to `ListView` and shows the new/updated `List`.